# I get an error when installing laravel or when I try updating composer. How do I resolve it?

Tags: laravel-5

I get this error

> "require(/var/www/html/data_security/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/data_security/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17"

when installing laravel or when I try updating composer. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you using homestead, xampp, mampp? Did you mess with `index.php` from the public folder?

Comment: fedora server. No any new installation too has the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fresh installation you will need to run **composer install** instead of composer update. I faced similar issue and composer install did the trick for me.